# I can not use libc, yet I have to reallocate and allocate memory using C

Tags: c, linux

Here is my code,

```
char buf[1];
int count=0;
while( Read(fileID, buf, 1)==1)
{
        contents = (char *)realloc(contents,(iVal+1)*sizeof(char));
        contents[count]=buf[0];
        count++;
}
```

Now that I can not use libc, how would I do the reallocation. The problem is that I do not know the size of the file I am reading so I have reallocate. The same problem exists with malloc as well.

Comment: If you are not using `libc` what are you using? Your program gets compiled against and gets linked to __________?

Comment: Why can't you use "libc"? Also where is 'realloc' from, when libc isnt available? Which platform is this?

Comment: This is Linux X64 using GCC, as of now I am using LIBC but I can't any longer so I am using system calls. Given that constraint, I can not use realloc hence why I am here for help

Comment: **Why**, specifically, can you not use libc?

Comment: It's just a constraint I have based on the assignment.

Comment: You'll need to tell us more about your assignment.  I'd guess that it doesn't mean to insist that you implement your own heap manager.  Your question mentions reading a file - won't this imply use of other system calls?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx

Comment: I need to read a file and store the contents of it. Since I do not know the size of the file, I am using realloc. Is there an alternative using arrays?

Comment: Exactly what are the rules for your assignment? You do realize that realloc is not trivial to implement, and writing a fully functioning, well working heap manager is several hundred lines of code without makiing it overly complicated. Of course you can do that if you want, but it's kind of pointless when there is a C library out there...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `libc` or another library with a memory management functions (malloc/realloc/free equivalents) you have to write your own memory manager.
If you are writing a kernel module for Linux you probably have access to `kmalloc(9)` and `kfree(9)` and perhaps even `krealloc`. If not, then you have to write your own memory management functions.

Answer (score 0):

lseek can tell you the size of the file before you read anything in, so you don't need a realloc() loop. mmap() can bring it into memory so you don't need malloc()/free() either.

Comment: for example if the file has "Hi Ron", I need it to return 5 that way my array can be of size, so I can copy the content of the file over using system calls, that was the whole purpose of my realloc so I can do it dynamically withotu specifying the size first

Comment: "info lseek" reports:" Upon  successful  completion,  lseek returns the resulting
       offset location as measured in bytes from the beginning of
       the file.  Otherwise, a value of (off_t)-1 is returned and
       errno is set to indicate the error."          (use SEEK_END argument, obviously).

Comment: Again, you don't need to create an array at all if you call mmap(); it will return a pointer to where the O/S has mapped the file into memory. But you will need to know how big the valid memory is that the mmap()-returned pointer points to, so lseek() can give you that.